# Why multi-touch events using touchpad (laptop) is not working in this Qt program?

Tags: qt

I am trying to handle mult-itouch events in this simple QWidget based program but not able to receive any touch events.

```
"MyWidget.h"

#include <QWidget>
class QPaintEvent;
class QEvent;

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
    bool event ( QEvent * event );


};


"MyWidget.cpp"

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
}

void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *evt) {

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.fillRect(rect(),QColor(0,255,0));
  //  painter.drawText(QPoint(rect().left(),rect().top()),"Hello world");
}

bool MyWidget::event(QEvent *event){
    if(event->type() == QEvent::TouchBegin ||
            event->type() == QEvent::TouchEnd ||
            event->type() == QEvent::TouchUpdate ){

        qDebug() <<"Touch events";
    }
    else if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick) {
        qDebug() <<"double click";

    }

    return QWidget::event(event);
}
```

Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: How does multitouch on your touchpad work with other apps? Which exact events do you try to catch?

Comment: Qt 4.8.1 version I am using !! It is working in QtCreator itself and I am able to use pinch and zoom to zoomout and zoomin in editor.

Comment: Did you get this working? I am currently facing the same problem with Qt 4.8.1 und 4.8.5 on Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Comment: I finally found out how to make touch event work (see answer).

Answer (score 0):

To make touch events work add the following to your MainWindow:

```
MyWidget *myWidget = ...;
setCentralWidget(myWidget);
```

In the MyWidget constructor add:

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents);
//grabGesture(Qt::PinchGesture);
//setAttribute(Qt::WA_InputMethodEnabled);
//setFocusPolicy(Qt::WheelFocus);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_StaticContents);
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't work for me. Any suggestions?